# A sequence For You: E K E K E B D C A, C E A B,?

Tags: letter-sequence

***E K E K E B D C A, C E A B,***

Continue the sequence.
 I'm sure you'll need nothing else, though if you do, I'll be adding some clues.

*Edit: Longer string, as a hint*

Comment: sounds like words of a song.... :)

Comment: Sounds like the words of a song... Edit: @user2408578 GMTA! :-)

Comment: The title of the song might be "A [something] For You"

Comment: Yes, it seems like all these editions gave a clue :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have it!

> E A B C?

The reasoning:

> It's the opening to Fur Elise, after being subject to a kind of "modulo 12". The Ks become D#, which gives you your opening sequence. The comma's indicate a tied note -- these along with the pattern of the first five notes were the give away for me.

Comment: About the K: After G, H = A#, I = B#, and so on. Furthermore, O = Ab, P = Bb, and so on. Good job.

Comment: @AlbertMasclans Great, that's what I was looking for :-) Thanks!